# tailwind not loading colors

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

Having simple html:

*public/index.html*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body class="text-red-600">
  some text
</body>
```

where the css was obtained from `tailwindcss -i src/styles.css -o public/styles.css`

*src/styles.css*:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

*tailwind.config.js*:

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

the red color from `<body>` tag does not apply. Are default tailwind classes imported into `public/styles.css`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the `public/index.html` file is not covered by the `content` file globs in your Tailwind configuration. You must ensure that source code files that use Tailwind classes are covered by the `content` file globs, otherwise Tailwind will not scan these files and will not generate CSS rules for class names present. Consider [reading the documentation on configuring `content`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration).

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{html,js}",
    "./public/index.html",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: I am beginner to tailwind, what is this configuration for anyway?

Comment: Consider [reading the documentation on configuring `content`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration), it tells you all about it.

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned `**content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"]**` in the tailwind.config.js file .So it will apply css for file inside the src directory with html and js extension. so html file should be inside the `src` folder. Therefore Folder structure should be `src/index.html`.
But if you want apply css without src folder then you have to mentioned that path in `tailwind.config.js` file like this.

```
content: [
    "./src/**/*.{html,js}",
    "./public/index.html",
  ]
```